# QGIS expression selecting features intersecting single buffer that has certain distance to the buffered feature

Tags: qgis, buffer, expression

I am looking for an expression in QGIS that allows me to select polygon features (layer 1, red polygons), that intersect more than 50 percent of the buffer ring around a point feature of another layer (layer 2, green point).

The buffer does not touch the buffered feature. It has a certain distance to it. Ideally I would not need to create a new layer for this.

I want to use this expression for the field calculator. Combined with CASE WHEN THEN, the polygons in layer 1 that intersect more than 50 percent of the buffer ring will get the value "good".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of the following may achieve your objective.

You haven't specified how the buffer ring is defined. I have arbitrarily given it an outer radius of 1000 and inner radius of 500, with 50 segments.

Also, I've just assumed that the green point is feature ID = 1 in  (which you will need to replace with your layer ID).

In short:

- Create an outer ring and inner ring based on the green point
- Take the difference of those to create your buffer ring
- Take the intersection of the buffer ring and each polygon
- Calculate the area of intersection
- Divide this by the total area of each polygon
- Check if greater than 0.5

```
area(
    intersection(
        difference(
            buffer(
                geometry(
                    get_feature_by_id(<layer2>,1)
                ),1000,50
            ),
            buffer(
                geometry(
                    get_feature_by_id(<layer2>,1)
                ),500,50
            )
        ),$geometry
    )
) / $area > 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I specify: The buffer shoud be around all features (green points) in layer 2, other asumptions are perfect. I adopted your expression to my case: 
CASE WHEN area(intersection(
        difference( buffer(geometry('layer 2'),1000,50),
            buffer(geometry('layer 2'),500,50)),$geometry)
) / $area > 0.5 THEN  'medium' 
 WHEN area(intersection(
        difference(buffer(geometry('layer 2'),499,50),
            buffer(geometry('layer 2'),1,50)),$geometry)
) / $area > 0.5 THEN 'good'
ELSE 'bad' 
END
I receive the error message: cannot convert to feature. U know why?

Comment: The ```geometry``` function in Expression Builder takes a feature argument, not a layer - hence the error message: "cannot convert to feature"

Comment: If you want to deal with multiple buffer rings, you will need to define your problem more carefully. For example, what happens if the rings overlap? And what if a polygon overlaps 30% of one buffer ring, and 40% of another? Is that good or bad?

Comment: Thanks again! Is there a way to refere  "geometry" in expression builder  to another layer, not a feature?                                                  Regarding overlapping bufferrings respectively if a polygon overlaps several bufferrings: every overlap with a  bufferring should count, the area of overlaps of one polygone with bufferings should be summed up, regardless if the bufferrings overlap themself. (sorry for beeing inaccurate before, I am new to the community)

Comment: Geometry in expression builder can't refer to a layer. However, there are sometimes tricks that can be used to sum up results across multiple features of a layer. Remember to go back and edit the original question with clarifications (and possibly extra screenshots).

Comment: You may in fact be better off asking your more detailed requirements as a separate question, referencing this one.